# Why is Cursor.requery() marked "deprecated"?

Tags: android, cursor, android-loadermanager

Cursor.requery() is a very common method while using it to refresh a ListView's content. But why is this method marked "deprecated"? I can't understand the reason on the API docs very clearly.

Cursor.requery() API:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#requery()

Can anyone please explain the reason any further? Thanks:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it was done because new [Loaders API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/loaders.html) was introduced to simplify querying Cursors asynchronously.

As deprecation note says

> Don't use this. Just request a new cursor, so you can do this asynchronously and update your list view once the new cursor comes back.

that's what we should be using.

*update*

It seems that it can also be related to deprecation of `Activity.startManaginCursor`:

> startManagingCursor(Cursor c)
>   This method is deprecated. Use the new CursorLoader class with LoaderManager instead; this is also available on older platforms through the Android compatibility package. This method allows the activity to take care of managing the given Cursor's lifecycle for you based on the activity's lifecycle. That is, when the activity is stopped it will automatically call deactivate() on the given Cursor, and when it is later restarted it will call requery() for you. When the activity is destroyed, all managed Cursors will be closed automatically. If you are targeting HONEYCOMB or later, consider instead using LoaderManager instead, available via getLoaderManager()