# Why is Cursor.requery() deprecated while SQLiteCursor.requery() is not?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I understand why [`Cursor.requery()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#requery()) would be deprecated - we do even have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073341/why-is-cursor-requery-marked-deprecated) which I read.

However today I found [`SQLiteCursor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor.html), which seems to be a subclass, and its [`SQLiteCursor.requery()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor.html#requery()) looks still ok in the official documentation.

Does anyone know why? Is this some kind of docs bug, or is `SQLiteCursor.requery()` any different from its counterpart?

Comment: When in doubt, read the code. I recommend grepcode.com as it's got some handy reference tooling

Comment: @dot `SQLiteCursor` calls `super.requery()`, which is both predictable and weird.

Comment: I'd say that makes it obsolete as well